# So do we always need variable to point objects in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37726461/3798182) answer, which says

```
NSString *string = [NSString new]; // A variable string referring a string object;
string = @"john"; // The object, string refers to is now "string"
```

Theoretically NSString is a class and string is an object which is given memory by [NSString new] code, Along with this I have read somewhere that in Objective-C, We always have pointer objects.

I am trying to understand it in real life example, Suppose **I go to Toyota Agency (NSString Class)** to purchased **Toyota Prius(String object).** And now I have **my school bag(john) left is the car** which is in my basement parking.

1. So string is a Pointer Object or Pointer variable, Is this my Prius ?
2. Is it referring to object in memory, memory is garage or Agency ?

Can any one please help to make it clear How an variable, pointer and object are related to each other ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is NSString stringWithString returning pointer to copied string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890814/why-is-nsstring-stringwithstring-returning-pointer-to-copied-string)

Comment: @Sneak yes it is duplicate of answer which i already mentioned in my question, but not what you are suggesting, anyways thanks.

Comment: Your question link is not the same as my comment duplicate. I am not sure what more you need to know, did you read the duplicate link? Everything you need to know is there, unless you want to know something more?

Comment: @Sneak I am sorry but the accepted answer of your duplicate link talks about returning pointer to a copied string, but i just want to know about a simple pointer, instead of arguing why not help me and explain string is a pointer or variable and how they both are related to object.

Comment: I am not arguing, I am trying to point you to the multiple threads made about this already. However, I took the time to find you a site that explains everything for you about NSString http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsstring and how the memory is accessed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254502/nsstring-allocation-and-initializing a good thread for you too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Object & Variable are (in this context) *syntactical sugar*, both can be used invariably.
    Yes, that is your *Prius*
2. It is referring to the *value at* memory occupied by the object `@"john"`

*School bag*  & *john* are not the same thing. 
*john* is the value stored at the memory location pointed by `string`.
From what you are stating, *school bag left is the car*, *school bag* looks like a attribute of the `string` object.
So,

```
 Toyota_Agency prius = [Toyota_Agency new];
 prius = @"john";
 prius.schoolBag = @"Some school bag";
```

Comment: So can i say prius is "Pointer variable" or "Pointer Object" and lets say we did not allocate memory yet `Toyota_Agency *prius;`

Is this just a variable or object as memory is not allocated which it can point to ?

Comment: Yes, `Toyota_Agency *prius;` currently points to nothing